# Split Column but associate with first column values SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have values design numbers that increase or change by few last characters e.g 30200XXX X000 changes to 30200XXX X010. They are stored at a table on the same column, the old number is before the old, for display purposes, i want the New Number to show on the right column of the Old in the same Row. Is there a way I can do this in SQL?

Here is my simple query that i use to pull the data

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE (LATEST_DCC_NO,")
  , RTRIM(A.PRT_NO)
  , COALESCE(SUBSTR(C.TGT_DC_PRT_NAME,1,20),'')AS "PART NAME"
  , A.SUP_NO
  , B.SUP_NME
  , A.TGT_SHPTO_CDE
  , A.MTC_MODEL
  , A.EFF_BG_DTE
  ,A.EFF_END_DTE
  ,A.PRT_QTY
   FROM XXX.XXA1 A LEFT OUTER JOIN XXX.XRT1 C ON C.TGT_XC_PRT_NO = A.PRT_NO
  , PXX.PUXSM1 B
    WHERE SUBSTR(A.MTX_MDE,1,1) IN('K')
    AND A.SUP_NO = B.SUP_NO
    ORDER BY 2
```

This is what I am currently getting

```
OLD/ NEW PRT_NUM
3000TKK Z003
3000TKK Z004
3000XXX X010
3000XXX X020
51000ZA K001
51000ZA K002
```

This is my desired result

```
OLD_PRT_NUM NEW_PRT_NUM
3000TKK Z003    3000TKK Z004
3000XXX X010    3000XXX X020
51000ZA K001    51000ZA K002
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: Your query gets 10 columns but you show only 1 in the results with a different name.

Comment: @joes Is `few last characters` == `last exactly N characters`? If yes, then what’s the number `N`? If no, then how to get these `few last characters` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming, that `few last characters` are those after the space.

```
with tab (PRT_NUM) as (values
  '3000TKK Z003'
, '3000TKK Z004'
, '3000XXX X010'
, '3000XXX X020'
, '51000ZA K001'
, '51000ZA K002'
)
select 
--  substr(PRT_NUM, 1, 7) || ' ' || min(substr(PRT_NUM, 9)) OLD_PRT_NUM
--, substr(PRT_NUM, 1, 7) || ' ' || max(substr(PRT_NUM, 9)) NEW_PRT_NUM
  substr(PRT_NUM, 1, locate(' ', PRT_NUM)-1) || ' ' || min(substr(PRT_NUM, locate(' ', PRT_NUM)+1)) OLD_PRT_NUM
, substr(PRT_NUM, 1, locate(' ', PRT_NUM)-1) || ' ' || max(substr(PRT_NUM, locate(' ', PRT_NUM)+1)) NEW_PRT_NUM
from tab
group by 
--substr(PRT_NUM, 1, 7)
substr(PRT_NUM, 1, locate(' ', PRT_NUM)-1);
```

Comment: Mark, thank you, this works with the sample data I provided. The ideal situation was to make it dynamic, and the most of the time the changes happen on the last for characters. Hope this explains better!

Comment: The solution provided returns the desired result on your sample data. If it doesn’t work on some other sample data, please, provide it with the desired result.